# Approximating NP-complete problems

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity

Say that for a particular problem, e.g., the independent set problem, it has been shown that no polynomial-time algorithm exists to solve it.

Could we get around this by finding an algorithm which approximates the solution to a certain accuracy?

That is, would the result above bar the existence of an algorithm which finds a maximum independent set to an accuracy of 0.5? I.e., it is guaranteed to be less than 0.5 away from the size of a maximum set? (And hence implying that it actually *is* a maximum independent set.)

It seems to me that the latter wouldn't violate our proofs of non-tractability, which are discrete in nature, while still giving an answer that satisfies the problem from a practical perspective.

Comment: There is a class of problems called APX Hard, such that unless NP=P, there are exist no polynomial time approximation schemes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We do not know for certain that independent set cannot be solved exactly in polynomial time. However, it is considered unlikely, and this is the famous P$\neq$NP conjecture.

In cases where exact optimal solutions cannot (probably) be found in polynomial time, it is natural to look for approximately optimal solutions. Algorithms tackling this are known as *approximation algorithms*. If an algorithm always returns a solution whose value is within $\rho$ of the optimum, then we call it a *$\rho$-approximation algorithm*, and say that its *approximation ratio* is $\rho$.

A good example is MAX-3SAT, in which we are given a 3CNF formula, and our goal is to find an assignment maximizing the number of satisfied clauses. The corresponding decision version is a generalization of 3SAT, and so it is NP-complete. However, if we choose an assignment at random, it satisfies $7/8$th of the clauses in expectation, and we can in fact deterministically find such an assignment. Since the optimal solution satisfies at most a $1$-fraction of the clauses, this algorithm has an approximation ratio of $7/8$. It is a consequence of the PCP theorem that it is NP-hard to do any better (this is a result of Håstad). We say that MAX-3SAT is *NP-hard to approximate within $7/8+\epsilon$* for any $\epsilon > 0$.

The independent set problem is much harder than MAX-3SAT. Indeed, it is NP-hard to approximate within $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. The best approximation algorithm known has approximation ratio $O(n(\log\log n)^2/\log^3 n)$ (as per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Approximation_algorithms)).

In practice, independent set can probably be approximated better, but this is different to formalize, since it is not clear what properties *real-world* graphs satisfy. For random $G(n,1/2)$ graphs (in which each edge is chosen with probability $1/2$ independently), there is a $1/2$-approximation algorithm (the approximation ratio is with high probability over the choice of the graph).

Sometimes one considers *smooth analysis* of algorithms to model real-world instances. The idea is that real-world instances are noisy, and so instead of being interested in a specific graph $G$, we should be looking at a "neighborhood" of $G$ formed from graphs close to $G$ (differing by a relatively small number of edges). It could be the case that some algorithm has good approximation ratio on most of the graphs in the neighborhood of *any* graph $G$. I am not aware of any such analysis for independent set.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Is there any book you would recommend that deals with approximation algorithms in general? I would guess CLRS might touch on it.

Comment: There are many books, which are easy enough to find on the web. Since I haven't read any of them, I can't recommend any one in particular.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius At least two nice ones come to mind. There's one by Vazirani and another one by [Williamson and Shmoys](http://www.designofapproxalgs.com/).

Comment: @Juho Thanks, it seems like a really good one. http://www.amazon.com/Approximation-Algorithms-Vijay-V-Vazirani/dp/3540653678

Answer (score 4):

To supplement Yuval's answer (since I've already written this out!):

If we assume a proof exists showing NP-complete problems cannot be solved in polynomial time (a very important corollary for such a proof would be that $P \neq NP$), such a proof would not invalidate any of the existing methods we have for coping with NP-complete problems:

- A brute force algorithm may be fine if instances of the problem are small.
- Sometimes the structure of problem instances can be used to solve it more quickly (2SAT vs. SAT).
- Sometimes certain parameters of problem instances can be used to solve the problem faster (CLIQUE with $k=10$ is solvable in ${\binom{n}{k}}$ ~ $n^k$).
- Heuristics can be used to find a good enough solution: Backtracking, genetic algos, local search...
- Approximation algorithms (like your suggestion) can be used to find sub-optimal but good enough solutions.

An example of an approximation algorithm can be given for MAX-2SAT. MAX-2SAT is the problem of finding the maximum number of clauses that can be simultaneously satisfied by an assignment to the variables of a 2-CNF (a boolean formula in conjunctive normal form with clauses that contain 2 literals). Each variable in a boolean formula can either be $0$ or $1$, so we just flip a coin to decide whether we assign $0$ or $1$ to each variable. With this approach, we can easily find an assignment to each variable that satisfies up to 75% of the clauses!

None of these techniques contradict our assumption that NP-complete problems have been proven to be unsolvable in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had no idea about 2SAT -- I was under the (false) impression that the problem was unsolved.

Comment: I think it's important to make a distinction here: A probabilistic polynomial time algorithm that approximates solutions to MAX-2SAT is not a solution to MAX-2SAT. Another very important observation is that **all NP-hard problems have solutions.** This means MAX-2SAT has a solution, but it does not have polynomial running time (which renders the solution impractical). We say "**2SAT has a polynomial time algorithm**." We don't say "2SAT is solved." Finally, it is true that $2SAT \in P$, but I am not sure how you deduced that given my example of MAX-2SAT. Something to think about.

Comment: When I said "the problem [is solved]", I meant "the problem of finding a polynomial-time algorithm for 2SAT is/was solved". Pardon my abbreviation.

Comment: MAX-2SAT can be approximated much better, to within $0.943\ldots$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Maximum-2-satisfiability for the number). Assuming UGC, this is best possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example: Take a graph with n nodes. Determining whether there is a cycle of length n is NP-complete. Now take "travelling salesman without triangular equation". Set the distance to 1 if two nodes are connected, and n^2 if they are not connected. If there was a cycle then the shortest tour has length n, otherwise it has length at least > n^2. Our inability to find an approximation comes from the fact that if there was a cycle, then there just isn't any near-optimal solution.

Or take "minimum number of colors required to color a planar graph". This is trivially solved if 0, 1 or 2 colors are needed, NP-complete to determine that the solution is 3, and there is always a way to color a graph with four colours. If the solution is 3, there is no approximation less than 33 percent away.

Comment: You could of course claim that 3 3/7th colours are required when two are not enough, and stay within 1/7th or 14.29% of the correct answer, but that's a bit like cheating :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are some NP-complete problems for which it has been shown that even getting an approximation to the solution is already NP-complete. I don't remember details now. It does depend on the problem, others are amenable to getting approximations efficiently.